# SSL Apache, Port 443 is in use

Tags: apache, ssl, centos, port

I'm trying to install my ssl certificate in Apache 2.2.15 but it returns with the error:

```
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
```

It seems that the Java is using this port, it would be possible to remove?

Comment: Off topic, but what's your evidence? `netstat` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determine which program is using the port `netstat -pant | grep :443` Usually **Tomcat**, **nginx**, or other applications use it.